# Verify php certificate in node.js

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, rsa

I have the following php function which verifies a certificate:

```
<?php

function raven_check_sig($data, $sig) {
    $key_path = '/path/to/pubkey.crt';
    $key_crt = file_get_contents($key_path);
    $key = openssl_get_publickey($key_crt);

    $result = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($sig), $key);

    openssl_free_key($key);

    if ($result == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I'm in the process of porting my application to node.js but I can't work out how to implement this function.

I have tried:

```
function checkSignature(data, sig, kid) {
  var keyPath = '/path/to/pubkey.crt';
  var key = fs.readFileSync(keyPath);

  var verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
  verifier.update(data);
  var res = verifier.verify(key, sig, 'base64');

  if (res) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

but this seems to always return `false`.  I have two problems that I think might be what causes this to fail:

1. I don't know whether `RSA-SHA256` is the correct algorithm to verify the certificate as I couldn't work out what `openssl_verify` does.
2. I don't know what the eqivalent to calling `openssl_get_publickey` is, assuming I do need something like that.

The contents of the file `pubkey.crt` is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the correct algorithm was SHA1:

```
function checkSignature(data, sig) {
  var keyPath = '/path/to/pubkey.crt';
  var key = fs.readFileSync(keyPath);

  var verifier = crypto.createVerify('SHA1');
  verifier.update(data);
  var res = verifier.verify(key, sig, 'base64');

  if (res) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So everything now works :)

Comment: I'm sorry to bring this up, but what would that `kid` parameter in `checkSignarute(data, sig, kid)` ?

Comment: It wasn't used, I have removed it from this example.  The `kid` was the keyID and allowed this function to be used to check against one of a set of public keys in the original code, but I removed that feature since it wasn't actually used.

Comment: Thank you anyways, it helped me a lot!